# What can't be done in native react native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I know there are native modules, but those aside, what can't be done in react native.  Also, is there anything that can't be done even with native modules?

Comment: There are billions of things you can't do with React Native. E.g. creating a Moon

Comment: Your question is too broad for a proper answer. Could you please get more specific. What do you want to do? Why do you ask this question?

Comment: Games like *Clash of Clans* would be very hard to do purely with React Native.

Answer (score 2):

You should see who is using react native: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/showcase.html

- Facebook
- Airbnb
- Instagram
- ...

So it is pretty much fits any use case **besides** anything very computational/performance heavy.

I also suggest this quick, short video of awesome Reinder: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I7haR6ktX5I

Comment: Where have you read that React Native cannot be used for Gaming? I just stumbled across this https://formidable.com/blog/2016/09/15/introducing-react-game-kit/

Comment: Yes you can, what I meant is that it is not THE choice for 3d mobile games.

Answer (score -1):

The question is **too broad**, basically **anything** you can do with **JavaScript, CSS, HTML plus Many Native stuffs** can be done in React Native, so basically you can do anything as long as you have the ability to do that... just there is a concern about some performance with Medias and CPU consuming stuff, You question is like somebody asks, what we can do with HTML, CSS & JavaScript for example, the answer is this: it's up to you and your skills and creativity!

Comment: React Native doesn't use CSS and HTML, so you what said isn't true

Comment: @Lian please do some study before voting and leave a comment, so what's this to you in React Native? <WebView source={{html: '<p>Here I am</p>'}} /> or const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  bigblue: {
    color: 'blue',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    fontSize: 30,
  },
  red: {
    color: 'red',
  },
}); ??????????????????

Comment: React-Native tries to make it easy for web developers who know React. But the whole point is to move away from WebView and use native elements. StyleSheet tries to mimick CSS but definitely isn't.

Comment: So that's all about it, React N using those in the upper level which we code, can be written in JS, CSS and HTML, if you discussing about what's happening behind the scene, it's a different topic, it's like for example you say in Less.js, we not writing CSS, we writing JS, when engine accept HTML, CSS and JS, mean you can write your app by knowing these only! If there is an engine which changes all our code to Obj-C for example, it's not related, because the user doesn't need to know Obj-C to create those, StyleSheet.create all using CSS syntax(Even it's not), so for the programmer it's CSS...

Comment: Yes knowing the syntax does help but syntax is a very small part of being able to write in a certain language and framework. It's like saying just because you know xml syntax, you know html.